# ¿Por qué en varios países de Latinoamérica se usan mucho los diminutivos?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, diferencias-regionales

No he viajado por muchos países hispanohablantes de Latinoamérica, solo por Argentina, Chile y Perú. Sin embargo, he notado que en países como Perú, México (novelas), quizás hasta Colombia (espero no estar equivocado) usan mucho los diminutivos. Dicen mucho términos como `sobrinito/a`, `sillita`, `esquinita`, `esposito/a` (de esposo/a), `hijito/a`, `tacita` (de taza, no tácita), `amorcito`, `carita`, etcétera. También noté que en ciertas zonas de Argentina, más en el Noroeste y Cuyo, también tienen esta costumbre aunque un poco más limitada.

Personalmente, quizás por la costumbre de mi zona, esta utilización no pasa por alto y me viene la duda de porqué esto sucede en algunas zonas y otras no.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que los diminutivos no se usan solo para expresar que algo es pequeño o insignificante. También se usan, y supongo que este será el caso, para hablar con cariño. Aquí en el sur de España también son muy comunes, muchas veces nos reímos con mi madre porque es muy dada a usarlos. Incluso mi familia me llama a mí usando un diminutivo de "Carlos". Si alguien te habla con diminutivos será porque se siente cómodo hablando contigo y no debería molestarte (es mi opinión). Si no fuera así usarían un lenguaje más formal, libre de diminutivos.

Comment: @Charlie Claro, entiendo. Tiene sentido porque son muy comunes cuando hablo con la parte de mi familia que vive en Perú, por ejemplo. Sin embargo lo vi tan seguido, inclusive en las calles y con gente que uno no conoce (hablándome a mí), que por ahí pensé que en esos lugares era la forma "estándar" digamos. Y honestamente no percibo el "cariño" con los diminutivos en lo absoluto, entonces para mí a final de cuentas suena muy raro. ¡Pero tranquilamente puedo ser yo el problema! Ya que lo percibo distinto. Muchas gracias por tu comentario y opinión, tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Podría ser también lo contrario a lo que piensas. A veces me pasa que una palabra la tengo que usar en diminutivo porque usarla sin él me sonaría demasiado formal. Seguramente habrá países donde este efecto suceda con más frecuencia. En todo caso, es una pregunta interesante acerca del uso del lenguaje, pero para tratar el aspecto acerca de cómo te sientes tal vez debas preguntar en el foro de IPS.

Comment: @Charlie Sí, mi idea era hacerlo lo más objetivo posible, porque quiero saber si en realidad hay algo de fondo, ya sea histórico, cultural o lo que fuese, que explique algún estilo de evolución distinta del lenguaje en ciertas zonas causante de esta utilización. Esto puede estar relacionado con los distintos significados de palabras en distintas zonas, se me ocurre, pero quizás no. De todos modos, sentí la necesidad de aclarar cómo me llegó la duda y que no pretendo ofender a nadie con un potencial mal uso de mis palabras.

Comment: I voted to close because this appears to be a cultural thing more than a linguistic thing.

Comment: @aparente001 sure, whatever, please yourself. Where should I ask this question instead in your opinion?

Comment: @user5389726598465 Por lo visto en algunos paises se usa la palabra en masculino: [mecedor](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=mecedor)

Comment: @walen I appreciate that.

Comment: @user5389726598465 nunca había escuchado o leído eso antes, tampoco sé lo que es un caballo mecedor, tampoco sé el significado de mecedor/a, aunque no veo la relación con lo que estaba preguntando... y, ¿qué causa ese cambio de palabra en el texto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estoy revisando el [capítulo 9.6 de la *Nueva Gramática*](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QeBypzRFABBzjJPl) de la RAE, acerca de las interpretaciones de los diminutivos. Es muy extenso como para reproducirlo entero, pero da una idea de la cantidad de matices que se pueden conseguir con un diminutivo, aparte de los habituales.

Pongo algunos ejemplos que me han llamado la atención:

- En los sustantivos que denotan acciones y sucesos se suele obtener una interpretación temporal ('breve', 'de corta duración'), como en *paseíto*, *viajecito*. Aunque otras veces el contexto deja claro que no es la brevedad lo que se destaca: *Uff, qué viajecito*.
- Convierte sustantivos incontables (*siento mucho dolor*) en contables (*noto un dolorcito*).
- Puede intensificar o rebajar la cualidad: *cerquita* puede ser 'muy cerca', pero *guapito* puede ser 'guapo con reservas'. O incluso ponerla en grado máximo: *el coche era nuevecito* por 'completamente nuevo'.
- Algunos diminutivos han pasado al habla común y hasta admiten nuevos diminutivos: de *ahorita mismo* se puede obtener *ahoritita mismo*.
- Su uso varía según las regiones: *fritito* sugiere 'muy frito' en algunos sitios, 'apetitoso' en otros e incluso 'ligeramente frito' en otros. Y a veces cambia el significado de la palabra original: *agarraditos* sugiere 'en actitud cariñosa'.
- Se usan mucho en el lenguaje empleado con los niños.

Todo esto viene a que con los diminutivos se consiguen muchos y muy variados matices que con el habla neutra no se obtienen o son más difíciles de conseguir. Por supuesto, el propio carácter de la gente hará que se tienda más a usar estos diminutivos en unos países que en otros, pero eso ya es un tema de personalidad. Podemos quedarnos con que la RAE recoge en su *Gramática* tu misma inquietud en el párrafo 9.6p:

> A los hispanohablantes europeos les ha llamado habitualmente la atención la mayor abundancia de diminutivos que caracteriza el español americano [...].

Aunque tampoco entra en explicar este fenómeno.

Comment: Muy buena la explicación, Creo que lo único que no dice es "respeto". Los empleados les hablan a sus jefes en diminutivos para mostrar respeto. "Le traigo una tacita de té don Juan?", "Se le ofrece un cafecito?" y varias frases por el estilo, donde el cafecito puede ser tan grande como lo quiera el jefe o el tecito refiriéndose a que es especial. La sensación general para los hispanohablantes americanos, creo que es de volver más suave algunas frases: "Quiero un poco", "quiero un poquito". Por lo infantil del estilo, diría que quiere conseguir el mismo efecto de un niño. ;)

Comment: Por una parte me alegra saber que la RAE tiene la misma inquietud, una lástima que no haya una explicación o teoría concreta sobre porqué. Pero entiendo la idea, con algunos de esos puntos me puedo relacionar, sin embargo otros me suenan muy raros porque no los escucho ni los uso habitualmente. Por ejemplo, “nuevecito” me suena inexistente y de ser necesario diría “nuevito”, pero no sé cuál es correcto. Mi abuelo paterno, que era peruano, me decía “nietecito”; y mi abuela materna, que es argentina, me dice “nietito.” Gracias a tu respuesta tengo un mejor entendimiento de varios usos dados.

Comment: There is an interesting article in _El País_ about the usage of diminutives in Spain https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2018/01/30/articulo/1517326334_976812.html and regional variation.

Answer (score 6):

Me he topado con el tema y me gustaría aportar algo más de información acerca del tema, ya que el asunto me interesa también mucho.

La publicación *Variación y variedad del diminutivo en español a través de dos corpus originales. Apuntes para su enseñanza como lengua extranjera* de Cecilia Criado y Diego María Antonieta Andión arroja información muy ilustrativa sobre el uso de los diminutivos. En la tabla que adjunto, se categoriza el uso del diminutivo en articulos de prensa según la variedad lingüística, y se aprecia cómo su uso va estrechamente ligado a la región.

> [image]

El artículo, sobre esto, incluye una reflexión de Andión Herrero:

> En  este  sentido,  el  contraste  de  uso funcional  del  diminutivo  en  nuestro  corpus  entre  el  español  europeo  y  americano  prueba  la desinhibición  del  primero  y  es  una  muestra  más  de  que “la actitud cultural, y su consecuente elección  de  elementos  lingüísticos  que  la  evidencian,  sería  diferente  entre  hispanoamericanos  y españoles.

De ahí que en el tema se vea tanto contraste de pareces y usos de los diminutivos.

En *Entre sistematización y variación:El sufijo diminutivo en España y en Hispanoamérica*, de Sien Callebaut, también se analiza el uso del diminutivo en los paises hispanohablantes. Se intenta trazar un patrón de sistematización para explicar el fenónemo por el que distintos diminutivos terminan por abrirse paso en el habla. Concluye de la siguiente forma:

> En  efecto,  en  el  español  americano  se  dan  como  uso  normal  formaciones  que  en  España resultan extrañas, hasta imposibles.  Hemos señalado reiteradamente que el español americano se distancia de la norma europea. Efectivamente, el español americano ha sido menos influido por  la norma  peninsular.  Por  ende,  una de  nuestras  observaciones  más  significativas  fue  la mayor  libertad  que  conoce  el  español  en  la  América  Latina.  En  consecuencia,  se  observa también  una  mayor  creatividad. Pese a  la  sistematización  que  surge  si  observamos  las variantes  hispanoamericanas,  existe  todavía   la   libertad  que  permite  al   hispanohablante explotar  esta  norma  vacilante.  Los  diminutivos  conocenun  dinamismo  claro  dentro  de  la América  Latina.  Este  dinamismo  influye  en  la  existencia  de  tantas  posibles  formaciones diminutivas.

A nivel particular, yo mismo noté, cuando comencé a leer a autores latinoamericanos (Cortázar, Borges, Vargas Llosa, García Márquez...) que el uso del diminutivo era mucho más frecuente y, también, más extensivo a diferentes categorías gramaticales en comparación al uso que se le da en la península española. Como en las publicaciones que cito, yo aprecio este uso como una forma, sobre todo, de experimentación y mayor libertad lingüística que termina por dotar de mayor vida al lenguaje. No solo por la riqueza y textura que aporta a nivel significativo y sonoro, sino también porque refleja la idiosincrasia de un pueblo; unos son más dados al trato cortés, diferenciando entre clases sociales; otros, a la lisonja y la afectividad...

Comment: Excelente respuesta, bienvenido/a al sitio

Answer (score 4):

Creo que todo lo que mencionó Charlie en su respuesta es correcto, pero quisiera agregar algo que me parece muy importante (dese mi experiencia viviendo en Colombia, donde se utilizan los diminutivos muchísimo en el habla diaria):

Las formas diminutivas afectan mucho los sentimientos expresados por una frase -- suelen hacer que la oración se perciba de manera más suave y más cortés. Los diminutivos tienden a bajar la intensidad emocional de cualquier cosa que uno dice.

En cierto sentido, utilizar los diminutivos tiene el efecto opuesto a utilizar las groserías.

"Deme un cafecito por favor" tiene el efecto opuesto a el de "DAME UN MALDITO CAFÉ YA!"

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y qué bueno que lo hiciste porque también me parece importante. Si a mí me dijeran “deme un cafecito,” entonces yo literalmente voy a traerle un café en una taza pequeña (creo que se llama pocillo). No logro identificar el cariño _en ese ejemplo particular_. Primero porque “deme” en Argentina es una conjugación formal, si fuese informal sería “dame”; segundo porque si fuese formal, siento la necesidad de tomar las cosas más literalmente que sentimentalmente porque no entro en un ambiente sentimental. Al menos yo personalmente. ¡Muchas gracias por tu adición!