# ¿Se considera el uso de los diminutivos una forma de lenguaje humilde?

Tags: cortesía, diminutivos

Hace poco, en *[¿Por qué en varios países de Latinoamérica se usan mucho los diminutivos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24002/12637)*, uno de los puntos que se comentaron fue el uso de los diminutivos en frases como:

> ¿Le traigo una tacita de té, don Juan?
>   ¿Se le ofrece un cafecito?

En su día se dijo que se usaban estos diminutivos como forma de suavizar las frases. Sin embargo, hoy me he acordado del lenguaje humilde usado en el japonés. En este idioma existe varias formas de lenguaje honorífico, dado que en la sociedad japonesa se tienen muy en cuenta las clases de cada uno. Si estás hablando con un superior hay dos formas de lenguaje honorífico: el *[sonkeigo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_honor%C3%ADfico_japon%C3%A9s#Lenguaje_respetuoso)*, que sirve para hablar con sumo respeto acerca de las acciones que atañen a tu interlocutor; y el *[kenjōgo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_honor%C3%ADfico_japon%C3%A9s#Lenguaje_humilde)*, que sirve para hablar con suma humildad de las acciones que te atañen a ti mismo.

Entonces caí en la cuenta del paralelismo, aunque no recordaba (ni recuerdo ahora) haber leído en la *Nueva gramática* nada acerca del posible uso de los diminutivos como forma de cortesía por parte del hablante hacia su interlocutor. Así, si le dices a tu jefe:

> ¿Le traigo una tacita de té?

se podría considerar que no es que le vaya a traer una taza pequeña, sino que el diminutivo implicaría una cortesía hacia el jefe, haciéndole ver que no le va a costar esfuerzo alguno el prepararla y llevársela.

Así pues, ¿se podría considerar el uso del diminutivo en estos casos como una forma de lenguaje humilde, similar al *kenjōgo*?

Comment: No tengo experiencia personal en el uso de *kenjōgo*, pero mi impresión al estudiar japonés hace años fue que se trata de un sistema más estructurado que nuestro humilde diminutivo (y es parte de un sistema de honoríficos más grande todavía, el *keigo*).

Comment: @pablodf76 por supuesto, mi intención no es comparar ambos sistemas. El _kenjōgo_ es, como dices, un sistema establecido, estructurado, con sus normas. Lo que quiero comparar es la idea subyacente, es decir, si el diminutivo se puede usar con el mismo propósito con el que se usa el _kenjōgo_ (aunque a su manera y dimensión, claro está).

Answer (score 3):

Los diminutivos castellanos han sido ampliamente estudiados en su aspecto morfosintáctico y también semántico-pragmático. La mayor parte de los estudios, lamentablemente, aparecen en publicaciones que son total o parcialmente inaccesibles. Pero para todos está claro que el diminutivo no tiene sólo la función literal de "empequeñecer" alguna cosa, sino que tiene variadas connotaciones afectivas, siendo una de ellas la de suavizar expresiones fuertes o demasiado directas.

María Antonia MARTÍN ZORRAQUINO, Universidad de Zaragoza, «[Sobre los diminutivos en español y su función en una teoría de la
cortesía verbal (con referencia especial a un cuento de
Antonio de Trueba)](https://minerva.usc.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10347/12235/42b%20Mart%C3%ADn%20Zorraquino.pdf?sequence=1)»:

> Los diminutivos, marcas de la subjetividad del hablante, de su visión
>   afectiva del mundo, se prestan especialmente bien a reforzar la imagen
>   positiva del interlocutor. Pueden, por tanto, intensificarla. Se
>   utilizan, así, a veces, en actos expresivos reforzadores de la
>   cercanía entre los interlocutores: *¡Ya estamos los dos solitos!*, *¡Qué
>   bien estamos juntitos!*, etc. Y, por medio de dicha intensificación, se
>   prestan a compensar cualquier acto amenazador contra la imagen de
>   aquellos (positiva o negativa), ya que, según señala Haverkate
>   (1994: 28), la cortesía positiva “no solo se manifiesta en los actos
>   de habla intrínsecamente corteses, también se maneja para mitigar
>   actos de habla no corteses”. Así, utilizamos diminutivos, por ejemplo,
>   para compensar una orden: *tráeme una botellita de limonada*; o para
>   dulcificar una prohibición: *no vuelvas más tarde de las doce a casita*,
>   y, especialmente, para amortiguar el efecto negativo de una
>   información no deseada: *estás más gordita*; o de una opinión no deseada
>   tampoco: *has estado pesadito*. Los diminutivos son, así, marcas
>   eficaces para la expresión de la cortesía positiva en el marco de la
>   teoría de la cortesía verbal comentada.

La teoría a la que se alude es de [Brown y Levinson](http://urbinavolant.com/pragmaubu/2016/05/13/principios-teoricos-de-la-cortesia-brown-y-levinson/).

Otro punto que mencionan algunos autores es que el diminutivo con frecuencia no es en sí o principalmente un modificador semántico del sustantivo (o adjetivo, o adverbio) al que sintácticamente modifica, sino que actúa como una marca sobre el discurso, modificando la proposición que lo contiene. En efecto, cuando uno dice *necesitaría un vasito de agua*, no está pidiendo un vaso pequeño; el diminutivo modifica sintácticamente a la palabra *vaso* pero el oyente promedio no lo percibe así, sino como una forma de suavizar el tono del pedido.

De la misma manera, las [formas corteses del japonés](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_honor%C3%ADfico_japon%C3%A9s) no expresan realmente una modificación semántica. Son, sí, bastante más variadas que la derivación de los diminutivos castellanos, pero no implican diferentes significados de las cosas, sino un cambio en la actitud del hablante frente al oyente.